# Is it possible for Instrumented tests to create coverage for a library module?

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco, multi-module

I am in the process of modularising the app I am working on and my coverage has dropped over 20% since splitting my instrumentation tests into the app module.

The app is being split into `app`, `core`, `custom`, where `core` is an android library and the other 2 modules are apps. The majority of the app's functionality will live in `core` and it is currently mostly tested through instrumentation tests which now reside in `app`.

Is there a way that instrumentation tests in an application module can generate a coverage report that will include library module sources?

I looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616769/android-instrumentation-tests-for-library-module-coverage) which bears great similarity to my dilemma but this seems outdated as `publishNonDefault` is deprecated and does nothing as libraries now publish all variants

My efforts are ongoing on [this PR](https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-android/pull/1541)

It will be difficult to complete modularisation with such a drop of coverage, I would expect the coverage to be unchanged post modularisation.

EDIT: I have created a repro project [here](https://github.com/macgills/MultiModuleCoverageIssue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventual answer came from [here](https://github.com/tramalho/unified-code-coverage-android/blob/mixed-languages-multi-module/jacoco.gradle) so all credit to them. Posting the contents of the file here for anybody looking in the future

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "$jacocoVersion"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    group "Reporting"
    description "Generate Jacoco coverage reports."

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination file("${rootProject.buildDir}/coverage-report")
    }

    def javaClasses = []
    def kotlinClasses = []
    def javaSrc = []
    def kotlinSrc = []
    def execution = []

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']

    rootProject.subprojects.each { proj ->
        javaClasses   << fileTree(dir: "$proj.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
        kotlinClasses << fileTree(dir: "$proj.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
        javaSrc       << "$proj.projectDir/src/main/java"
        kotlinSrc     << "$proj.projectDir/src/main/kotlin"
        execution     << fileTree(dir: proj.buildDir,
                includes: ['jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec',
                           'outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/**/*.ec'])
    }

    sourceDirectories = files([javaSrc, kotlinSrc])
    classDirectories = files([javaClasses, kotlinClasses])

    print execution

    executionData = files(execution)

    doLast() {
        print "file://${reports.html.destination}/index.html"
    }
}
```

FileFilter probably needs some improvement for a modern Android application eg Dagger/ViewBinding.

I applied this in my `app/build.gradle` and after running `gradlew jacocoTestReport` the report with full coverage was present in `[projRoot]/build/coverage-report`.

Repro project has been updated with the solution.

Comment: The generated report's `index.html` file header is last scanned module name instead of `debugAndroidTest` which was shown on normal coverage reports. By any chance can we change the report heading to `debugAndroidTest` ?

Answer (score 0):

See the [JacocoMerge](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoMerge.html) task which can merge multiple jacoco execution files into a single file. You can then generate a [JacocoReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html) from the merged exec file

Comment: This is unfortunately not the solution, I think. I don't want a merged report (codecov handles that for me). I want a report in my `app` module the references code in my `core` module.

Comment: You can use `JacocoReport.additionalSourceDirs(...)` to add extra sources

Comment: I have to write my own task and specify this in it? Sorry but I don't know where this should go, in the jacoco plugin extension I only see `toolsVersion` & `reportsDir`

Comment: No, see my other answer. You'll configure one of the tasks added by the JaCoCo plugin

Comment: `jacocoTestReport` is for unit tests if I am not mistaken? I don't think this has bearing on the instrumentation coverage report run by `createDebugCoverageReport`? I will give it a try in my example project

Comment: Ah, you are using android. I'm not familiar with the android plugin. It's possible/probable that the JaCoCo tasks are the same type but named differently. You could do `tasks.withType(JacocoReport) {...} ` to configure the tasks instead

Answer (score 0):

No.

Just add your instrumentation tests to the module that has the code under test.

Was under a misconception that instrumentation tests could not be run on a library project due to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3604489/12225251), I have proposed an edit to reflect the up to date documentation.

EDIT: I later found a solution but honestly it probably should not be used and this is the path you should go down. Instrumentation tests probably shouldn't be used for coverage to begin with and unless you are stuck with legacy do not use the solution presented on this page.

Answer (score 0):

See the [JaCoCo plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_tasks) which show that a task named "jacocoTestReport" is added by the JaCoCo plugin. And you can see there's an "additionalSourceDirs" property on the [JacocoReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport:additionalSourceDirs) task

So you can do something like

```
apply plugin: 'java-library' 
apply plugin: 'jacoco' 
evaluationDependsOn ':another-project'
tasks.withType(JacocoReport) {
   def otherSourceSet = project(':another-project').sourceSets.main
   additionalSourceDirs.from otherSourceSet.allJava
   additionalClassDirs.from otherSourceSet.output
}
```

Comment: Very similar to your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057920/generate-coverage-for-other-modules). It seems like the custom configuration of the jacocoReport task is a bit more complicated than seen here. [This article](https://medium.com/@android2ee/playing-with-gradle-3-and-some-few-code-coverage-on-android-with-jacoco-47df7c9328ae) goes into more detail but is outdated I think as the location of the `.class` files is not as described

Comment: See my updates to use `tasks.withType{...}` and to configure `additionalClassDirs`